# Open totally new window when clicking on screen

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that open a pop-up window when user clicks on the screen. The problem is, if you click again, it will not open another pop-up, it will just "reload" the already opened window. There is a way to create another with second click on screen?

Here is the code:

```
function makePopunder(pUrl) {
var _parent = (top != self && typeof (top["document"]["location"].toString()) === "string") ? top : self;
var mypopunder = null;
var pName = (Math["floor"]((Math["random"]() * 1000) + 1));
var pWidth = window["innerWidth"];
var pHeight = window["innerHeight"];
var pPosX = window["screenX"];
var pPosY = window["screenY"];
var pWait = 3600;
pWait = (pWait * 1000);
var pCap = 50000;
var todayPops = 0;
var cookie = "_.mypopunder";
var browser = function () {
    var n = navigator["userAgent"]["toLowerCase"]();
    var b = {
        webkit: /webkit/ ["test"](n),
        mozilla: (/mozilla/ ["test"](n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/ ["test"](n)),
        chrome: /chrome/ ["test"](n),
        msie: (/msie/ ["test"](n)) && (!/opera/ ["test"](n)),
        firefox: /firefox/ ["test"](n),
        safari: (/safari/ ["test"](n) && !(/chrome/ ["test"](n))),
        opera: /opera/ ["test"](n)
    };
    b["version"] = (b["safari"]) ? (n["match"](/.+(?:ri)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n["match"](/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
    return b;
}();

function isCapped() {
    try {
        todayPops = Math["floor"](document["cookie"]["split"](cookie + "Cap=")[1]["split"](";")[0]);
    } catch (err) {};
    return (pCap <= todayPops || document["cookie"]["indexOf"](cookie + "=") !== -1);
};

function doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY) {
    if (isCapped()) {
        return;
    };
    var sOptions = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=" + pWidth.toString() + ",height=" + pHeight.toString() + ",screenX=" + pPosX + ",screenY=" + pPosY;
    document["onclick"] = function (e) {
        if (isCapped() || window["pop_clicked"] == 1 || pop_isRightButtonClicked(e)) {
            //return;
        };
        window["pop_clicked"] = 1;
        mypopunder = _parent["window"]["open"](pUrl, pName, sOptions);
        if (mypopunder) {
            var now = new Date();
            document["cookie"] = cookie + "=1;expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + pWait))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
            now = new Date();
            document["cookie"] = cookie + "Cap=" + (todayPops + 1) + ";expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + (84600 * 1000)))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
            pop2under();
        };
    };
};

function pop2under() {
    try {
        mypopunder["blur"]();
        mypopunder["opener"]["window"]["focus"]();
        window["self"]["window"]["blur"]();
        window["focus"]();
        if (browser["firefox"]) {
            openCloseWindow();
        };
        if (browser["webkit"]) {
            openCloseTab();
        };
    } catch (e) {};
};

function openCloseWindow() {
    var ghost = window["open"]("about:blank");
    ghost["focus"]();
    ghost["close"]();
};

function openCloseTab() {
    var ghost = document["createElement"]("a");
    ghost["href"] = "about:blank";
    ghost["target"] = "PopHelper";
    document["getElementsByTagName"]("body")[0]["appendChild"](ghost);
    ghost["parentNode"]["removeChild"](ghost);
    var clk = document["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
    clk["initMouseEvent"]("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    ghost["dispatchEvent"](clk);
    window["open"]("about:blank", "PopHelper")["close"]();
};

function pop_isRightButtonClicked(e) {
    var rightclick = false;
    e = e || window["event"];
    if (e["which"]) {
        rightclick = (e["which"] == 3);
    } else {
        if (e["button"]) {
            rightclick = (e["button"] == 2);
        };
    };
    return rightclick;
};
if (isCapped()) {
    return;
} else {
    doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY);
};
}
makePopunder('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

Comment: Could you cut down the code to the essentials please? This is a lot of fluff. Also, it might help you realise the problem by forcing yourself to cut code.

Comment: Also an example jsfiddle would be practical.

Comment: Just curious if you have a fear of the dot syntax? There are times when you can't use it, but really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to run the 'open' command with the name attribute set. This creates a reference of that name to the window, when you then run that command again with the same window it will use the window that already has that reference. The solution would be to run `open` without `name`:

```
open(url, '', ...)
```

[Here is some documentation on open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: @MikeHoeks Glad I could help... even though it is with someone creating pop-ups ;).